# Stored Procedure Where Clause Parameters

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, where-clause

I've got an ASP.net search page where the user can enter one or more search criteria.  The page calls a stored procedure to query a MS SQL Server 2008 db.

Part of the search criteria is single date or date range.  If the user supplies Date1, we search on a single date.  If the user supplies Date1 and Date2, we search on a date range.

My issue is coding this logic in the stored proc.

```
@Date1 datetime
@Date2 datetime
..other search params...
```

So there are three conditions:

1. Both @Date1 and @Date2 are null (the user is not searching on dates)
2. @Date1 is not null and @Date2 is null (the user is searching on a single date)
3. @Date1 is not null and @Date2 is not null (user is searching a date range)

I can't figure out how to structure the WHERE clause to handle each of the three possible conditions.

I'm familiar with `ISNULL()` and `COALESCE()`

Any tips or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the query you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BLABLABLA(
  @DATE1 DATETIME = NULL,
  @DATE2 DATETIME = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT COL1, COL2
  FROM THE_TABLE
  WHERE 
    THE_TABLE.DATETIMEFIELD BETWEEN 
      ISNULL(@DATE1, THE_TABLE.DATETIMEFIELD) 
      AND COALESCE(@DATE2, @DATE1, THE_TABLE.DATETIMEFIELD)
END
```

Another choice, losing some expressiveness but likely using indexes, could be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BLABLABLA(
  @DATE1 DATETIME = NULL,
  @DATE2 DATETIME = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT COL1, COL2
  FROM THE_TABLE
  WHERE 
    (THE_TABLE.DATETIMEFIELD >= @DATE1 OR @DATE1 IS NULL) 
     AND (THE_TABLE.DATETIMEFIELD <= @DATE2 
         OR THE_TABLE.DATETIMEFIELD = @DATE1
         OR (@DATE1 IS NULL AND @DATE2 IS NULL)) 
END
```

Comment: Rodrigo, thanks for the reply.  Will the the BETWEEN handle the case where just @Date1 is given?  That is, the user is just searching on where THE_TABLE.DATETIMEFIELD = @Date1?

Comment: if `@date2` is null, the `isnull` function will fall to the same column, so the where clause will be `datetimecolumn between @date1 and datetimecolumn`, and as `datetimecolumn = datetimecolumn`, the last part of the between clause will remain open for any possible value

Comment: the answer looks nice, but will using ISNULL prevent the possibility of an index being used on DATETIMEFIELD ? (i.e. sargability considerations)

Comment: Ok, I've improved the query so it will likely use a index in DATETIMEFIELD

Comment: I still see a problem.  If @Date1 is given and @Date2 is null, the code is always doing a >= @Date1.  The logic I want to create is: if only @Date1 is given then where datetimecolumn = @Date1

Comment: To search on a single date, I think what I'll do is just instruct the user to set the same date in @Date1 and @Date2 .

Comment: Ok, now the queries are fixed to follow the specifications

Answer (score 1):

You could try to create your SQL query as a string in the SP and then execute it, like this:

```
...
declare @sql varchar(500)
set @sql = 'select from myTable where 1=1'

if(@Date1 <> null)
    set @sql = @sql + ' and date1 >= '+ @date1

if(@Date2 <> null)
    set @sql = @sql + ' and date2 <= '+ @date2

print(@sql) -- for debug 
exec(@sql)
```

Comment: hey, it's not the perfect practice but works and in some cases it _is_ the most simple and effective way to build queries.

Comment: dynamic sql must be used only if there is no other choice. In this case, you can build sql expressions that can handle the requirements without any dynamic sql.

Comment: +1 for dynamic sql, Entity Framework and Linq to Sql generate dynamic sql at run time

Comment: I want to give -1 for string manipulation of this sort, but the vote goes down to -2, this post is neither bad nor good, don't want it to go down too much. But also agree with Rodrigo that not to use dynamic sql if it is not neccery.

Comment: @Rodrigo, as I admit your solution is more elegant in this particular case, I don't agree with the word Must in your first statement. Dynamic SQL can be much more legible and debugable than long and complex sql expressions. I've never done benchmarking but as far as I know there aren't real inconvenients from using dynamic sql.

Comment: *real inconvenients*? like sql injections, unexpected runtime exceptions, lack of execution plans, etc...

Comment: sql injections will always exist if data is not sanitized. about the other arguments I really don't have a clue, never had to deal with those. so thanks for the topic.

Comment: This is usually the most performant way to do a complex search with a lot of parameters that may or may not be filled in. I'm not a fan of dynamic SQl in general but the search query is what it excels at.

Comment: However, do not use dynamic SQl until you read this article:http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html